# How do I implement the BIRCH and CURE clustering algorithms?

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka

I am going to run BIRCH clustering algorithm in WEKA or in SPSS Clementine. Is there any package to install in WEKA or other software to run these algorithms?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Doesn't weka already include birch?

Comment: Here is BIRCH Clustering class in WEKA: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/datagenerators/BIRCHCluster.html

but, i could not know how can i use it in my weka? i use Weka 3.7 that has not BIRCH.

Comment: That class looks more like a data generator, judging from the path. It probably generates artifical data as it was used by BIRCH. For clustering, forget about Weka. It's really slow and offers just a few algorithms, some of them (OPTICS) not even fully implemented. And SPSS probably is not much better.